# In Silverlight UI thread, when doing InvokeAsync what happens?

Tags: multithreading, silverlight

I am trying to solve SL performance issues.
Up until now I had WCF calls which were executed by InvokeAsync.
Now, I changed it to use the BackgroundWorker.
Performance is greatly improved.

what can cause this? what does InvokeAsync did exactly that affected the UI thread? is it opening another UI thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes down to Synchronization contexts.  A thread may be associated with `SynchronizationContext` such as the `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` (which is the context of the UI thread and only contains this one thread).  WCF will complete an operation in the same Synchronization context that it began in, if there is no synchronization context associated with the thread it will use any thread in the thread pool.

Hence if you have several outstanding async operations all invoked from the UI Thread then all those operations will want to run their completion code in the UI Thread.  If a number of them complete at the same time the completion code will have to queue up waiting to be dispatched into this single UI thread.

Whereas when you invoke async operations in a Background worker its running in a thread from the thread pool and does not have special synchronisation context.  When those operations complete their completion code may run on any available thread in the pool (of which there are several).  So near simultaneous completions can all run in parallel on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF and Silverlight i recommend to use SynchronazationContext to save the main thread, all other thread will use this instance of SynchronazationContext to access the main thread (UI). You use it in this manner (Note: i generated a method that do this and all other methods will access this method to update the UI):

```
SynchronazationContext ctx = null;
void DoSomething()
{
    ctx = SynchronazationContext.Current;
    //Some algorithm here
    this.UpdatePic("Success !");
}
void ThreadProc()
{
    SendOrPostCallback callBack  = new SendOrPostCallback(UpdatePic);
    ctx.Post(callBack, String.Format("Put here the pic path");
}
void UpdatePic(string _text)
{  
    //This method run under the main method
}
```

In .NET 5.0 you can call this complicated functions by mark the method as async and write 'await' when you call the synchronous method - that make the synchronous method as asynchronous method and update the UI with the main thread.